# Unable to use NavigationService when using Protocol URI activation in Prism for Windows Runtime

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, prism

I am using the Prism-StoreApps with version 2.0.0 in a Windows 8.1 app.
Everything works fine for regular appstarts, but I am unable to use the NavigationService when my App is opened using URI protocol activation.

Here the onLaunchApplicationAsync method is not called, and I am unable to use the NavigationService in the onActivated method that is called by the system when the link is opened.

Anything I need to do manually in the onActivated method so everything is set up correctly?